# Delay svg onscroll animation from animating right after it appears on the screen

Tags: javascript, svg, window, screen, onscroll

i am currently developing a website where i used some svg technology! However, i have some svg icons that are animated on scroll but this happens as soon as they appear on the screen! The problem is that i need these icons to appear on the screen and instead of getting triggered straight away i need it to wait for the user to scroll i little bit more and then start animating! this is the js i used:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
drawLines();
});


function drawLines(){
$.each($(".red-line"), function(i, val){
var line = val;
drawLine($(this), line);
});
}


function drawLine(container, line){
var length = 0;
var pathLength = line.getTotalLength();
var distanceFromTop = container.offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
var percentDone = 1 - (distanceFromTop / $(window).height());
length = percentDone * pathLength - 500;
line.style.strokeDasharray = [length,pathLength].join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Measure the scroll distance with `.scrollTop()` and set the drawLines() to start after a specified distance (in the example 200):

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var sc = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (sc>200){drawLines();}
});
```

Comment: hey i just tried this! It indeed delays the icons from STARTING as soon as they appear on screen but the icons are pre-animated to the position as they would have been at that point of scrolling instead starting from the beginning! Do you understand what i am trying to say?

Comment: Try this in your code:  " - $(window).scrollTop() + 200"  or maybe " - $(window).scrollTop() - 200"

Comment: hmm i've tried both ways with other numbers than 200 and -200 in order to actually affect the icons but the effect is exactly the same as the first piece of code! It delays them yes, but the are already pre-animated! When i get to the position where they actually start animating again they are already half way drawn when the appear for the first time on the screen! : /